# Android - Activity navigation

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation

[image]

I have problem with activity navigation. I have 3 activities.

1) `ActivityA` is list of Invoice

2) `ActivityB` is list of Items of Invoice (invoice detail)

3) `ActivityC` is product list

- When user click on Invoice item in `ActivityA`, then I start `ActivityB` and show Invoice detail.
- When user click on PLUS button in `ActivityB`, I start `ActivityC` and user can select products into Invoice.
- When user click on BACK button in `ActivityC`, then `ActivityC` finishes and user is in `ActivityB`.

Ok, it is functional, but I need:

When user click on PLUS button in `ActivityA`, then create Invoice and directly start `ActivityC` for product selection. OK, I start `ActivityC`, user can select product. But problem is, when user click on Back button in `ActivityC`, I need to navigate back to `ActivityB` (to invoice detail) not to `ActivityA`. How can I do this?

What is the best solution for this problem?

Comment: First of all check this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: show code snippet

Comment: Show your code for rectifying your problem.

Comment: just use a flag. Activate the flag to a variable when user selects a product and depending upon the flag write the code on  onBackPressed()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to override the `onBackPressed` function in your `ActivityC` to handle the transition among your activities. Here's how you do it.

While you are launching `ActivityC` from `ActivityB`, start the activity like this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityC.class);
intent.putExtra("CallingActivity", "ActivityB");
startActivity(intent);
```

And while launching `ActivityC` from your `ActivityA`, you need to do the following.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityC.class);
intent.putExtra("CallingActivity", "ActivityA");
startActivity(intent);
```

Now in your `ActivityC` you need to check the value of the intent and save it somewhere. Then handle the `onBackPressed` function in your `ActivityC`.

```
String callingActivity = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_activity_c);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    callingActivity = bundle.getString("CallingActivity", null);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(callingActivity != null && callingActivity.equals("ActivityB")) super.onBackPressed();
    else {
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
       startActivity(intent); 
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In that case start Activity B from Activity C and finish Activity C.

```
void startActivityB(){
     Intent starter = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
     startActivity(starter);
     this.finish();
}
```

And ActivityA still will be in stack.

Comment: When I go A-->C-->B, it is ok, but when I go:  A-->B-->C then back button in C create B and after back in B navigate again to B instead of A, because B is in Stack twice.

Comment: <activity android:name=".ActivityB" android:launchMode="singleTop"/>   this will prevent to create same activity twice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that i think might work for you. On back press in Activity C .. fire intent for starting activity B .. this might help you..

Let me know if this worked for you! 
Else you need to show the code snippet..

Answer (score 0):

Override onBackpressed method in your activity c
try this one

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   //code any action you want at here
   Intent activityB= new Intent(ActivityC.this, ActivityB.class);
   startActivity(activityB);finish();
}
```

Hope this will work for you